# I incorrectly upvoted a post but now cannot reverse it. How can I?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-bydesign, down-votes, up-votes

I upvoted [a post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12226/are-there-any-cases-where-prepend-cannot-be-replaced-by-prefix/12227#12227) that, after some time and investigation, happened to be incorrect and misleading. Cf. my question ["If prepend is not part of English, why ther's no postpend, subpend? and who introduces them?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13325/if-prepend-is-not-part-of-english-why-thers-no-postpend-subpend-and-who-intr)

Why cannot I change my vote?
Can it be changed?

**Update:**
Casting a downvote on [mentioned above post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12226/are-there-any-cases-where-prepend-cannot-be-replaced-by-prefix/12227#12227) produces pop-up with yellow background:

> You last voted on this answer    Feb
>   11 at 18:40
>
> Your vote is now locked in   unless
>   this answer is edited   (click on this
>   box to dismiss)

I believe it is universal in all SE sites. I clicked them many times by an error or on purpose before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design -- there are too many exploits around unlimited undo and change of votes. Sorry.

Comment: Like what?  I see people repeating this all over the place, but no one can provide any evidence or rationale of it actually solving any problem.  It certainly doesn't prevent people from "tactically" downvoting competing answers.

Answer (score 3):

There's a time limit on changing your vote, as the message says. If you want to change your vote after that time limit, you need to either edit the answer yourself (if you have the reputation to do so), or get someone to edit it for you. I'm not sure how the suggested-editing function relates to this.

Comment: Thanks. And what is the time period during which I can change my vote?

Comment: @vgv8: I don't remember offhand. Something like 3 hours?